# Spell-checking and Kile

Tags: kile, spelling

I have been using texmaker for a long time and I decided to give Kile a try. When I miss-spell a word in Texmaker the spell-checker marks it red and right-clicking on the word shows me possible options.

In Kile this is not the case. On right-clicking a misspelled word, I get to see the different options (like cut paste, spelling etc). Then I have to click spelling and the possible choices pop-up.

It is not an inherently huge problem, but I am wondering is it possible to configure the spell-checking more akin to texmaker?

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 11):

Just make sure that automatic checking is enabled:

Tools > Spelling > Automatic Spell Checking

Comment: That only underlines the miss-spelled words with wiggly red arrows. It doesn't show possible correct options.

Comment: @DBS Well you have to right-click. Of course, I don't know how it works in your other editor. But I thought you had to right-click there, too.

Comment: @cfr the problem is that you have to right-click and then make another click on 'Spelling' to see the spell checking options...

Comment: @Andyk I don't have to click again. It is in a sub-menu, though, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @cfr The issue is in KILE you have to do one right-click for the menu and then once more for word choices. In Texmaker one right click shows the possible word choices. One click versus two clicks may not be a lot but it does become inconvenient when you are editing large documents. My question is if this can be modified in kile.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a proper solution for the spelling suggestions being two menus down, but I have a workaround that may improve a heavy user's workflow.

One can use keyboard shortcuts to bring up the spelling window, and immediately accept the first suggestion.

Setup:

- Tools menu > Configure Shortcuts...
- Type "Spelling" in the search box
- Assign a shortcut to "Spelling (from cursor)"

Usage:

- Move cursor before (doesn't need to be exactly before) the word that's marked as mis-spelled
- Press the shortcut you set before
- Hit Alt+R to replace with first suggestion, or choose one of the other options by mouse/shortcut

It sounds complicated, but if the first suggestion is correct, it's a very fast way to correct mistakes.